# HTML to PDF - java - batik

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am trying to export a html div tag(which has svg as well) to PDF using batik. I can achieve to transform just teh svg to PDF. But with div I am facing errors. Any suggestions on how to use html content to PDF using batik.

I referred to this, https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html

SAMPLE HTML which I am trying to use, `<div id="toexport"><svg>MY CHART</svg> <div>OTHER CONTENTS like LEGENDS</div></div>`

Comment: batik does not support html, only SVG

Comment: maybe you should elaborate a bit more about where the div tag comes from or what you could do to it prior to passing it into batik, is it a server script?

Comment: I have a chart drawn using d3 in svg, and legends are drawn below the concerned chart. So while exporting the chart to pdf, i would like to couple both chart and legend in the same. this is my scenario. @StefanHegny

Comment: @JeganS, I suggest to edit the question to show the export code you try to use - maybe you should just select an svg child of the toexport id or need an xslt transform to extract the svg, I currently can't tell (but maybe someone else drops in who sees it clear)

Comment: Since Batik only supports SVG--not HTML tags such as `<div>`--perhaps you should convert your HTML to SVG before passing it over to Batik.